# Longtable caption problem

Tags: tables, captions, longtable

The following LaTeX code generates a table:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{float, longtable}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}%{-3.0cm}{}
\centering\footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\begin{longtable}{!{\vrule width 0.8pt}*{8}{c|}c!{\vrule width 0.8pt}}
\Xhline{0.8pt}
\thead{ID da \\ ORF}
    & \thead{Quadro}
        & \thead{Incício}
            & \thead{Fim}
                & \thead{Comprimento \\ (bp)}
                    & \thead{Função inferida}
                        & \thead{Nº de acesso da\\ sequência de proteína\\ usada na inferência}
                            & \thead{Organismo ao qual\\ pertence essa proteína}
                                & \thead{(e-value do BLASTp),\\(\% de identidade),\\(\% query cover),\\(\% subject cover)} \\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
\endhead
\multicolumn{9}{r@{}}{\scriptsize \itshape contig 8}
\endfoot
\Xhline{0.8pt}
\endlastfoot

    \hline 
    ORF8
    & +1
        & 15232
            & 16674
                & 1443
                    & \thead{bifunctional ADP-dependent\\NAD(P)H-hydrate\\ dehydratase/NAD(P)H-hydrate\\epimerase }
                        & \thead{PIT77859.1}
                            & \thead{\textit{Limnohabitans sp.} \\ \textit{B9-3}}
                                & \thead{(2e-146),\\(52),\\(97),\\(98)} \\
    \hline 
    ORF10
    & +1
        & 19024 
            & 19416
                & 393
                    & \thead{Uncharacterised protein}
                        & \thead{CFN68428.1}
                            & \thead{\textit{Bordetella} \\ \textit{pertussis}}
                                & \thead{(2e-20),\\(57),\\(96),\\(55)} \\
    \hline 
    ORF16
    & +2
        & 13373 
            & 13717
                & 345
                    & \thead{Uncharacterised protein}
                        & \thead{CFO12503.1}
                            & \thead{\textit{Bordetella} \\ \textit{pertussis}}
                                & \thead{(5e-18),\\(65),\\(54),\\(86)} \\                            
    \hline 
    ORF17
    & +2
        & 13988 
            & 15235
                & 1248
                    & \thead{FAD-dependent\\oxidoreductase}
                        & \thead{WP\_062471622.1}
                            & \thead{\textit{Variovorax} \\ \textit{boronicumulans}}
                                & \thead{(0.0),\\(65),\\(97),\\(98)} \\
    \hline 
    ORF26
    & -1
        & 19706 
            & 17448
                & 2259
                    & \thead{ribonuclease R}
                        & \thead{WP\_108301238.1}
                            & \thead{\textit{Limnohabitans sp.} \\ \textit{JirII-29}}
                                & \thead{(0.0),\\(82),\\(98),\\(100)} \\                            
    \hline 
    ORF29
    & -1
        & 12968 
            & 12075
                & 894
                    & \thead{elongation factor Ts}
                        & \thead{WP\_104797623.1}
                            & \thead{\textit{Limnohabitans sp. } \\ \textit{TS-CS-82}}
                                & \thead{(0.0),\\(87),\\(94),\\(95)} \\                            
    \hline 
    ORF33
    & -1 
        & 4901
            & 4395
                & 507
                    & \thead{OmpH family\\outer membrane\\protein}
                        & \thead{WP\_066695178.1}
                            & \thead{\textit{Comamonadaceae} \\ \textit{bacterium}\\\textit{CCH4-C5}}
                                & \thead{(7e-94),\\(76),\\(100),\\(100)} \\                            
    \hline 
    ORF34
    & -1
        & 3404 
            & 2961
                & 444 
                    & \thead{3-hydroxyacyl-\\(acyl-carrier-protein) \\dehydratase FabZ}
                        & \thead{WP\_056277791.1}
                            & \thead{\textit{Hydrogenophaga sp.} \\ \textit{Root209}}
                                & \thead{(8e-95),\\(86),\\(98),\\(99)} \\                            
    \hline 
    ORF35
    & -1
        & 1001
            & 363
                & 639
                    & \thead{ribonuclease HII}
                        & \thead{WP\_108360097.1}
                            & \thead{\textit{Limnohabitans sp.} \\ \textit{Rim8}}
                                & \thead{(7e-128),\\(83),\\(96),\\()} \\                            
    \hline 
    ORF37
    & -2
        & 17431
            & 16679
                & 753
                    & \thead{SDR family\\oxidoreductase}
                        & \thead{WP\_076201382.1}
                            & \thead{\textit{Rhodoferax} \\ \textit{koreense}}
                                & \thead{(1e-148),\\(80),\\(99),\\(99)} \\                            
    \hline 
    ORF39
    & -2
        & 10660
            & 9827
                & 834
                    & \thead{phosphatidate\\cytidylyltransferase}
                        & \thead{OJW85673.1}
                            & \thead{\textit{Alicycliphilus sp.} \\ \textit{69-12}}
                                & \thead{(4e-120),\\(66),\\(99),\\(99)} \\
    \hline 
    ORF40
    & -2
        & 7198
            & 4901
                & 2298
                    & \thead{outer membrane\\protein assembly\\factor BamA}
                        & \thead{WP\_027478712.1}
                            & \thead{\textit{Curvibacter} \\ \textit{gracilis}}
                                & \thead{(0.0),\\(71),\\(100),\\(100)} \\                            
    \hline 
    ORF41
    & -2
        & 2950 
            & 2156
                & 795
                    & \thead{acyl-ACP--\\UDP-N-acetylglucosamine\\ O-acyltransferase}
                        & \thead{WP\_066705960.1}
                            & \thead{\textit{Curvibacter} \\ \textit{delicatus}}
                                & \thead{(1e-171),\\(83),\\(100),\\(100)} \\                            
    \hline 
    ORF42
    & -3
        & 20910 
            & 19870
                & 1041
                    & \thead{ribosomal protein\\S12 methylthiotransferase}
                        & \thead{OYY19752.1}
                            & \thead{\textit{Burkholderiales} \\ \textit{bacterium}\\\textit{35-55-47}}
                                & \thead{(0.0),\\(91),\\(100),\\(75)} \\                            
    \hline 
    ORF45
    & -3
        & 13827
            & 13075
                & 753
                    & \thead{30S ribosomal\\protein S2}
                        & \thead{OYU32113.1}
                            & \thead{\textit{Comamonadaceae} \\ \textit{bacterium}\\\textit{PBBC2}}
                                & \thead{(1e-175),\\(91),\\(99),\\(100)} \\                           
    \hline 
    ORF46
    & -3
        & 11988
            & 11266
                & 723
                    & \thead{UMP kinase}
                        & \thead{WP\_077562881.1}
                            & \thead{\textit{Polaromonas sp.} \\ \textit{C04}}
                                & \thead{(2e-167),\\(95),\\(99),\\(100)} \\                            
    \hline 
    ORF47
    & -3
        & 11235 
            & 10675
                & 561
                    & \thead{ribosome recycling\\factor}
                        & \thead{WP\_019573212.1}
                            & \thead{MULTISPECIES: \\ \textit{Curvibacter}}
                                & \thead{(2e-118),\\(85),\\(100),\\(100)} \\                            
    \hline 
    ORF48
    & -3
        & 9825
            & 8635
                & 1191
                    & \thead{1-deoxy-D-xylulose-5-phosphate\\ reductoisomerase}
                        & \thead{PUE32828.1}
                            & \thead{\textit{Limnohabitans sp.} \\ \textit{Jir61}}
                                & \thead{(0.0),\\(81),\\(98),\\(97)} \\                            
    \hline 
    ORF49
    & -3
        & 8622
            & 7231
                & 1392
                    & \thead{RIP metalloprotease\\RseP}
                        & \thead{WP\_108360101.1}
                            & \thead{\textit{Limnohabitans sp. } \\ \textit{Rim8}}
                                & \thead{(5e-162),\\(54),\\(98),\\(99)} \\                            
    \hline 
    ORF50
    & -3
        & 2136
            & 973
                & 1164
                    & \thead{lipid-A-disaccharide\\synthase}
                        & \thead{WP\_100146888.1}
                            & \thead{MULTISPECIES: \\ \textit{Limnohabitans}}
                                & \thead{(0.0),\\(74),\\(96),\\(99)} \\                            
    \hline 
    ORF51
    & -3
        & 366
            & 1
                & 366
                    & \thead{RNA methyltransferase}
                        & \thead{WP\_056743611.1}
                            & \thead{\textit{Acidovorax sp.} \\ \textit{Root568}}
                                & \thead{(3e-49 ),\\(64),\\(96),\\()} \\                            
\end{longtable}
\caption{\textit{\Large{Contig 8}}}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

But, as you can see, the caption "Contig 8" only appears at the final table. I thought that the code line `\multicolumn{9}{r@{}}{\scriptsize \itshape contig 8}` would act, esthetically,  like the `\caption{}` function. Is there a simple way that I can make the caption "Contig 8" appear in every single table? Just like the last one?

Comment: `\caption` shoudl be in the table foot so at the start of the `longtable` before `\endfoot`  unrelated but don't use `\centering` with `longtable` (it does nothing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\caption` should be in the table foot so at the start of the longtable before `\endfoot` .